# Android how to perform certain tasks on headset button click?

Tags: android, service, android-intent

Alright, so I'm writing an app to make an external headset perform certain functions. I'm trying to replicate functionality similar to this guy:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.kober.headset

The list of things it can make the headset button click do is: play/pause, previous track, redial last phone #, launch specified app, etc. I don't know how to do this stuff though! Sort of lost with how to get started here. I'm also kind of confused how the overall program flow should work.

Right now I can register button clicks via a broastcast receiver and correctly and pass that number (single/double/triple click) to a service to run in the background. I'm using a background service so the user doesn't need to be in the app to use the functionality.

Am I on the right track? How do I go about making clicks play/pause music, next/previous track, etc? Are there certain intents I should be using?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I on the right track?

Be sure to stop your service when it is no longer needed (e.g., after you have determined the clicks and performed the operation). Otherwise, I see no problems there.

> How do I go about making clicks play/pause music, next/previous track, etc?

First, write a music player app. There are no documented and supported APIs to "play/pause music, next/previous track, etc" for most of the several thousand music players out there.

Comment: A music player app? Doesn't the user already have access to various music players? Because what I want is to be able to, say, double click and skip track while the user is already in their music player of choice. 
Or am I to make a general app that encompasses all music being played...? Kinda lost here, but thanks for the response

Comment: @maxcollins: As I wrote, there are no documented and supported APIs to "play/pause music, next/previous track, etc" for most of the several thousand music players out there. Hence, if you want those features, you will need to implement them in your own music player app.

Comment: Alrighty. But then I'm curious - how does the existing Headset button controller (linked in OP) perform the functionality I described? Basically for any music player you're in, they make it so that the headset button can be configured to skip to next track, play/pause, etc. Did they program that for a case-by-case basis for the most popular music players?

Comment: @maxcollins: "how does the existing Headset button controller (linked in OP) perform the functionality I described?" -- for the AOSP Music app, if they support that player, they probably use some undocumented, unsupported, only-a-fool-does-this techniques. I do not know if they support any other players and, if so, whether they are using documented/supported techniques for those players.

Comment: OK well in that case... It looks like I should limit my scope, perhaps to whatever default player there is. So getting started, will creating a MediaPlayer object be my best bet?

Comment: @maxcollins: Well, `MediaPlayer` is for *you* to play media. It is not to control some other media app. If you want to play media yourself (audio or video), `MediaPlayer` is a fine place to start. With respect to your "scope", there is no single "default player" -- different devices have different players, written and/or selected by their device manufacturers. The "default default" player -- the Music app from the Android open source project -- does not have a documented or supported API for play/pause, etc.

Comment: Dang that's a drag. Looks like I'm off to trying to solve a different problem them, thanks for the comments.